# Marsaglia: Given $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ from iid $x_i \sim N(0, 1)$, show that for any unit $v$ that $x \cdot v \sim N(0, 1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, euclidean-geometry

Given a random point in $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ formed from $n$ iid standard normal random variables $\mathbf{x}_i$ like so:

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{x} &= \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}_1 \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{x}_n \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align*}

Show that the length of the projection of $\mathbf{x}$ onto any unit vector $\mathbf{v}$ has a standard normal distribution. In other words, show that the dot product $\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{v}$ has a standard normal distribution when ${\lVert v \rVert}_2 = 1$.

The joint pdf, by multiplying the $n$ independent pdfs together, is:

\begin{align*}
  f(\mathbf{x}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n) &= (2\pi)^{-n/2} e^{-1/2(\mathbf{x}_1^2 + \cdots + \mathbf{x}_n^2)} \\
\end{align*}

I believe we want to show that this equals

\begin{align*}
  &= (2\pi)^{-1/2} e^{-1/2(\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{v})^2} \\
  &= (2\pi)^{-1/2} e^{-1/2(\mathbf{x}_1 \mathbf{v}_1 + \cdots + \mathbf{x}_n \mathbf{v}_n)^2} \\
\end{align*}

Am I right so far? How do I proceed to demonstrate equality between the two pdf equations?

Comment: Using the characteristic function is probably the easiest way to show this.

Comment: Ah, yes, the characteristic function approach works perfectly and easily. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDF way is perhaps not the best. It is easier to do the following:

1. Show that mean of $v\cdot x$ is $0$
2. Show that its variance is $|v|^2=1$
3. Show a linear combination of independent Gaussian random variables is a Gaussian random variable
4. Conclude that therefore $v\cdot x$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean 0 and variance 1, i.e., it is $\sim\cal N(0,1)$